# NoReverseMatch at /posts/ while using absolute url in django

Tags: python, django

In my model.py, i have define a class:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"id":self.id})
```

In url.py(Project url)

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),
]
```

In url.py(app url)

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', post_list),
    url(r'^create/$', post_create),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^update/$', post_update),
    url(r'^delete/$', post_delete),
]
```

In index.html

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
{% url "posts:detail" id=obj.id %}
<a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ obj.title }}</a><br/>
{{ obj.content }}<br/>
{{ obj.timestamp }}<br/>
{{ obj.updated_date }}<br/>
{{ obj.id }}<br/>

{% endfor %}
```

While reloading, it gives

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: The error shows that it can't find any pattern by that name, but that code doesn't match the code you posted here. Try clearing your `.pyc` files and restarting your server. Can you show the full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the `URLpatterns` and the `reverse` call look okay and works fine for me. I would check the view function has the argument `id` and that you are not loading a cached result. Also, it might be related to old `pyc` files being loaded, try delete them as @knbk suggested.

Comment: It worked after i recoded models.py and changing the posts namespace elsewhere. Thanks